# Making an j query ajax call work both on page load and with a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a datatable which gets it's data from an ajax call. Normally ajax runs when the page is loaded and gets the datatable filled with data.

But I want to add some search options to my datatable too. I can send the parameter to server side and get a dataset back with fiters.

What I want to do is, I want the datatable loaded with null parameters at page load, and with a button click send the ajax with parameters and get back filtered data.

What I tried is this

```
<script>
    //var searchInput ;//search için aramadaki değeri almaya çalışma

    $(document).ready(function TableData(searchInput) {
        var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

                if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                    return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
                }
            }
        };

        //var searchInput = $("#inpSearch").val();//search için aramadaki değeri almaya çalışma
        var DocumentTypeId = getUrlParameter('DocumentTypeId');
        var Type = getUrlParameter('Type');
        //console.log("dokumantip: " + DocumentTypeId);
        //console.log("tip: " + Type);

        var datatable = null;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
                "searching": false,
                "ordering": false
            });


            @*var dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action(  Inbox ? "InboxList" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder")";*@
            @*var dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action( Inbox ? "InboxListByType" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder")";*@

            if (Type == 1) {
                var dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action( Inbox ? "ERPListByType" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder")";
            } else if (Type == 2) {
                var dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action( Inbox ? "InboxListByType" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder")";
            } else if (Type == 3) {
                var dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action( Inbox ? "OutboxListByType" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder")";
            } else if (Type == 4) {
                var dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action( Inbox ? "DeletedDocumentsList" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder")";
            } else {
                //açılış ekranında default gelen kutusu e-TCGB gelsin
                var dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action( Inbox ? "InboxListByType" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder", new { DocumentTypeID = 3 })";
            }

            if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#expandabledatatable')) {
                $('#expandabledatatable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            }

            datatable = $('#expandabledatatable').dataTable({
                //"sDom": "Tflt<'row DTTTFooter'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
                //"processing": true,
                //info: false,

                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    "url": dataSourceUrl,
                    "data": { DocumentTypeId: DocumentTypeId, searchInput: searchInput },
                    "type": "POST"
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        "data": "Id",
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return "<label><input type='checkbox' value='" + data + "' name='chkGrid'><span class='text'></span></label>";
                        }
                    },
                    { "data": "@Html.Raw(Inbox ? "SenderCompany" : "ReceiverCompany")" },
                    { "data": "DocumentTypeName" },
                    {
                        "data": "RegistrationDate",
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return moment(parseInt(data.substr(6))).format('DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm');
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "RegistrationCode",
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            console.log(row);
                            return "<a href='@Url.Action("View","Folder")/" + row["Id"] + "'>" + data + "</a>";
                        }
                    },
                    { "data": "CustomsTransportType" },
                    { "data": "VehicleIdNo" },
                    { "data": null, "defaultContent": "" },
                    { "data": "ConsignorName" },
                    { "data": "ConsigneeName" },
                    { "data": "TotalNoOfPackages" },
                    { "data": "TotalGrossWeight" }
                ],
                iDisplayLength: 10,
                language: {
                    "info": "Toplam kayıt : \_TOTAL\_<br/> Gösterilen : \_START\_ - \_END\_",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first": "İlk",
                        "last": "Son",
                        "next": "İleri",
                        "previous": "Geri"
                    }
                }
            });



        });
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
            alert("test");
            TableData($('#inpSearch').val())
        })
    });



</script>
```

I tried to get the ajax event inside a jquery function with a single parameter so that I could be able to put inside my search button click. But I can' get it work as I want it to be.

EDIT:

data is returned from ActionResult as

```
string DatatableJson = Utility.DatatableToJson(ds.Tables[0]);

return Content("{ \"draw\": " + Draw + ", \"recordsTotal\" :" + TotalRows + " , \"recordsFiltered\": " + TotalRows + ", \"data\": " + DatatableJson + " } ");
```

ds is the datatable returning from Database via a stored procedure.

EDIT 2:

I noticed that

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
            //alert($('#inpSearch').val());
            var search = $('#inpSearch').val();
            TableData(search);
            $('#expandabledatatable').Datatable().draw();
        })
```

gives a "ReferenceError: TableData is not defined" error. So I think I have a problem with calling the function.

Comment: just by doing `$('#expandabledatatable').Datatable().draw()` inside your button click event will make the table do ajax call and build the table again

Comment: Just as a side node: One `$(document).ready(function () {});` does the trick. I don't know about any reasons to use it multiple times in the same file. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't have much experience with jQuery, I'm very new to this so you are highly probably right caramba

Comment: @Reddy, didn't work :(

Comment: @caramba You can have as many `$(document).ready(function () {});` as you like. Cramming everything into a single one is not necessary, it's even counter-productive because it would prevent modularization.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = Object.fromQueryString(window.location.search);

    $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
        searching: false,
        ordering: false
    });

    $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
        doSearch( $('#inpSearch').val(), url.Type, url.DocumentTypeId);
    });

    // click the button (do a search) on page load once
    $('#btnSearch').click();
});
```

Note that this uses [`Object.fromQueryString()` from sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/api/Object/fromQueryString), a very useful library that offers all kinds of helpful stuff. I included that because your `getUrlParameter()` function is broken and it's not worth fixing that. URL parsers have been written, use an existing one.

You can probably replace moment.js with [the Date functions provided by sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/api/Date/format) as well, if you do not want to increase the number of dependencies.

I have created a `doSearch()` function that does not depend on any data except what you pass in the arguments. This way the function can be re-used much easier.

```
function doSearch(searchInput, documentTypeId, type) {
    var dataSourceUrl;

    switch (type) {
        case 1: dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action( Inbox ? "ERPListByType" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder")"; break;
        case 2: dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action( Inbox ? "InboxListByType" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder")"; break;
        case 3: dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action( Inbox ? "OutboxListByType" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder")"; break;
        case 4: dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action( Inbox ? "DeletedDocumentsList" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder")"; break;
        default: dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action( Inbox ? "InboxListByType" : "OutboxList" ,"Folder")"; break;
    }

    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#expandabledatatable')) {
        $('#expandabledatatable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    }
    $('#expandabledatatable').dataTable({
        //sDom: "Tflt<'row DTTTFooter'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
        //processing: true,
        //info: false,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: dataSourceUrl,
            data: { DocumentTypeId: documentTypeId, searchInput: searchInput },
            type: "POST"
        },
        // etc ...
    });
}
```

Comment: That looks really nice but I need some confirmation from my lead before using another library sadly :(

Comment: You do not have to use sugar.js. I have included it because I happen to like it a lot, because it happens to offer a URL parser, and because libraries like this one tend to be tested very extensively. The point is, the function you currently use for URL parsing is broken and you should not use it. You can pick a better function that that one, but I would prefer one that comes from a well-tested library over one that you have copied off of some website.